# parcel-bundler won't install

Tags: html, css, terminal, web-frontend

new to web development and came across this error message while trying to build for production in the terminal.

Tried entering:
parcel build index.html

Error message I get:

Build failed.

@parcel/namer-default: Target "main" declares an output file path of "index.js" which does not match the compiled bundle type "html".

Not sure what this means since I am still learning. Any help would be appreciative. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I literally just found a solution after posting this question.

So I went inside, "package.json", file and cleared the "main": "index.js", and tried building the parcel again in terminal and it worked. Maybe the problem was the, "main": "index.js", had a 'index.js' and my index was in .html. So after clearing the,"main": "index.js", solved my problem.